# Get the number of time a class method has been invoked?

Tags: php, oop, method-chaining

Let's say I have this class.

```
class foo{
  function a(){
     return $this; 
  }
}
```

And I instantiate it as:

```
$O = new foo(); 
$O->a()
  ->a()
  ->a();
```

Is there any way to know, in that last function `->a()` how many times it was called before? 
So, I could output like `'method ->a() has been called twice before this.'` 
I would like to find out this, without using increment values like declaring a property and then increment it increment it, everytime it is called in a function.

I am just hopping if there is a hidden feature in OOP that can provide for this solution

Comment: What's wrong with an increment property? AFAIK there is no such "hidden feature" in *any* OO language.

Comment: why don't you want to increment a counter? and why would there be a hidden feature for this?

Comment: I meant, I am not skilled enough to know if OOP actually supports this feature.

Comment: What has this to do with OOP in general? It would be a language feature if you magically could track how often a method or function has been called. It doesn't really relate to OOP, it's possible to ask the same question for functional programming or procedural programming. Just implement a counter for it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [static variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) inside the method:

```
class foo{

  function a(){
     // $count will be initialized the first time a() was called
     static $count = 0;
     // counter will be incremented each time the method gets called
     $count ++;

     echo __METHOD__ . " was called $count times\n";
     return $this;
  }
}
```

Note that `static` has a different meaning when used inside a method or function and it has nothing to do with static class members - although it is the same keyword. It means that the variable will be created and initialized only once when the method has been called for the first time.

However, in the example above there is no way to reinitialize that counter. If you want to do that you may introduce a parameter or something like this. Also you may not use a `static` variable but an object property.. There are tousand ways to do it, tell me your exact application needs I may give a more specific example....

---

In comments it was suggested to use a decorator for this job. I like this idea and will give a simple example:

```
class FooDecorator
{

    protected $foo;
    protected $numberOfCalls;

    public function __construct($foo) {
        $this->foo = $foo;
        $this->reset();
    }

    public function a() {
        $this->numberOfCalls++;
        $this->foo->a();
        return $this;
    }

    public function resetCounter() {
        $this->numberOfCalls = 0;
    }

    public function getNumberOfCalls() {
        return $this->numberOfCalls;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
$foo = new FooDecorator(new foo());
$foo->a()
    ->a()
    ->a();

echo "a() was called " . $foo->getNumberOfCalls() . " times\n";
```

Comment: Not sure why the -1, it's a valid answer to a bad question.

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I wanted to avoid, when I said increment. But, if no others alternatives are found, then I guess I will have to use this.

Comment: @ANW check my update. There are 1000 ways to do. Tell me what you exactly want to achieve and I can help more

Comment: @OneOfOne Maybe because it doesn't answer the question exactly. An object property might be the better way. Otherwise multiple object may influence each other

Comment: Or you could decorate the original object and nor return `this` but an decorated view of the object... it really depends on what you want to do.

Comment: @Polygnome Yeah, using the decorator pattern sounds nice. Also it should fit a wide range of possible application needs. Why not answering this? :)

Comment: It is just my lack of knowledge which has led me into thinking there might be other ways to finding out, that what seemed as a trivial approach. Btw: I would love for simple example in decorator pattern, as I have been trying to grasp that concept supplemented with simple eaxmple.

Comment: Let's wait if @Polygnome will give an example as it was his idea. Otherwise I will do..

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks. This should feel like hitting two birds with one stone